# Помогите пожалуйста с блоком для выбора

Tags: javascript, html

У меня на сайте есть блок проверить возможность подключения 
https://internet-kz.info/
Есть список всех городов, улиц, и номеров домов которые подключены к Билайн в Казахстане! Как сделать что бы при вводе названия города выпадал список из того что есть! Что бы по Алматы показывались только улицы и дома Алматы ! А не полный файл в 30 000 домов, сколько примерно это стоит если заказывать у фрилансера??
Если есть пример и html код, что бы мог сделать мой программист ! Если там не сложно 
Заранее благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вот так на коленке это все решается. В `<input>` можно писать значение и он выведет подсказки либо же сразу выбрать из подсказки. По мере заполнения форма сама будет подбирать улицы и их дома.

```js
let data = [{
    city: "Алматы",
    data: [{
        street: "Абая",
        houses: [1, 34, 65, 87]
      },
      {
        street: "Сатпаева",
        houses: [2, 4, 5, 7]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    city: "Есик",
    data: [{
        street: "Спортивная",
        houses: [33, 3, 5, 7]
      },
      {
        street: "Сатпаева",
        houses: [25, 43, 54, 75]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    city: "Шымкент",
    data: [{
        street: "Какой-то город",
        houses: [343, 35, 52, 7]
      },
      {
        street: "Еще один город",
        houses: [245, 43, 54, 75]
      },
    ]
  }
];

let path = {
  city: null,
  street: null,
  house: null
}

$("body").append("<datalist id='citys'>" + data.map(item => "<option>" + item.city + "</option>").join("") + "</datalist>");

$("input[name='city']").on("change", (e) => {
  $("datalist[id='streets']").remove();
  $("datalist[id='houses']").remove();
  $("input[name='street']").val("");
  $("input[name='house']").val("");
  let elem = $(e.currentTarget);
  if (elem.val()) {
    let cityIndex = data.findIndex(item => item.city === elem.val());
    path.city = cityIndex;
    $("body").append("<datalist id='streets'>" + data[cityIndex].data.map(item => "<option>" + item.street + "</option>").join("") + "</datalist>");
  }
});

$("input[name='street']").on("change", (e) => {
  $("datalist[id='houses']").remove();
  $("input[name='house']").val("");
  let elem = $(e.currentTarget);
  if (elem.val()) {
    let streetIndex = data[path.city].data.findIndex(item => item.street === elem.val());
    path.street = streetIndex;
    $("body").append("<datalist id='houses'>" + data[path.city].data[streetIndex].houses.map(item => "<option>" + item + "</option>").join("") + "</datalist>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="city" id="city" list="citys">
  <input name="street" id="street" list="streets">
  <input name="house" id="house" list="houses">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как сделаю отпишусь ! Завтра буду  просить программиста

Comment: Вы с Казахстана :)??

Comment: @АнатолийБуренко да, с Алматы)

Comment: Спасибо большое еще раз ! Реально очень помогли ! Спасибо, на этом сайте можно искать специалистов которые буду делать работу за деньги ???